# AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute 'block_variable'

Tags: pytorch, fenics

I have written a subclass of torch_fenics. In this, the input is a vector from DG space. I use this input in the weak formulation and then calculate the solution. Further, I need the gradient of the solution with respect to the given input.

```
I get the following error log on running the same
```

~/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/function.py in apply(self, *args)
75
76     def apply(self, *args):
---> 77         return self._forward_cls.backward(self, *args)
78
79

~/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_fenics/torch_fenics.py in backward(ctx, *grad_outputs)
88         # Check which gradients need to be computed
89         controls = list(map(fenics_adjoint.Control,
---> 90                             (c for g, c in zip(ctx.needs_input_grad[1:], ctx.fenics_inputs) if g)))
91
92         # Compute and accumulate gradient for each output with respect to each input

~/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyadjoint/control.py in **init**(self, control)
38     def **init**(self, control):
39         self.control = control
---> 40         self.block_variable = control.block_variable
41
42     def data(self):

AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute 'block_variable'

Answer (score 1):

Don't import dolfin in your code. It will resolve the issue.